# mysqli_connect and mysql_connect does not exist in PHP 5.6.30

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using mysqli in my project and I think I have installed the extension properly.

My php.ini looks like this and Loaded Configuration File matches with httpd.conf, both are c:\php\php.ini:

```
 ..
 extension_dir = "/ext"
 ..
 extension=php_mysql.dll
 extension=php_mysqli.dll
 ..
```

**Problem:**

When I publish my website on *Apache24 Lounge* the statement `function_exists ('mysqli_connect')` becomes false, also`function_exists ('mysql_connect')` returns false too! I don't know why :(

However, when I create a test file (test.php), the statement `function_exists ('mysqli_connect')` returns true,when using `php -f test.php` that shows the `mysql_connect` and `mysqli_connect` both are installed and exist.

**Configuration**

I have the following products installed on Windows 10:

php 5.6.30, binary version X64, copied to C:\php

MySQL 5.7 Installed using its installer, tcpip port default 3306

Apache24 Lounge on C:\Apache24

Following address is added to `%path%`

```
 C:\Apache24\bin
 C:\php
 C:\php\ext
 C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin
```

Comment: have you created a web script with phpinfo() to display what it thinks is installed.  When run from the CLI it may have a different setup.

Comment: check ini file which is relevant to server. you can add phpinfo();  one of your php file and execute that request and try .

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Comment: @NigelRen `get_loaded_extensions()` shows mysql and mysqli when i use command prompt `php -f test.php` but when I publish my website to Apache24 I do not see mysql and mysqli in `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());`

Comment: @suresh I did, phpinfo(8) shows mysqli entry while using `php -f test.php` but it doesn't show mysqli entry when I add phpinfo(8) to my published into apache24 php file.

Comment: @Zich there are two php.ini will be used , one for console and another one for server. So you have to find that sever support ini file and you need to add the extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You might have two php.ini files, in Linux you may have something like

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Make sure they both have the mysqli extension enabled. The apache2 one is for any http requests.

Comment: I check loaded configuration file with phpinfo(1) and it was `C:\php\php.ini` ,which was the one I expected, httpd.conf also set to `c:\php\php.ini`

Comment: It this what it says in the phpinfo output from the web page?

Comment: Yes, Let me upload it somewhere

Comment: I don't believe it!, it works now!, I just installed IIS, because I thought it is apache's fault, but suddenly it is working

Comment: Good - but it's useful to know where the ini files are and how to use them.  Usually you only find these things out when things don't work (like up till now)

Comment: Well thanks for your comments, I can not accept your answer,Cause ini file were correct and it was web server side issue, But I believe yours worth an up ;)